# $select query on OData is hanging on simple request

Tags: asp.net, select, entity-framework-core, odata, ef-core-6.0

I'm trying to implement a very simple and basic OData support into a WebAPI .NET 6 project, following this forum https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/up-running-w-odata-in-asp-net-6/ advice.

I configured OData in Program.cs like this:

```cs
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddOData(options =>
        options.EnableQueryFeatures(null))
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```

and added a basic specific controller as the following:

```cs
[Authorize]
[Route("ext/[controller]")]
public class ExtendedController : ODataController
{
    private readonly IExtendedManager<MyType> _myTypeExtManager;
    private readonly ILogger<ExtendedController> _logger;

    public ExtendedController(IExtendedManager<MyType> myTypeExtManager,
                                ILogger<ExtendedController> logger)
    {
        _myTypeExtManager = myTypeExtManager;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<MyType> Get()
    {
        return _myTypeExtManager.GetAll();
    }
}
```

"IExtendedManager" is injected as a scoped service in the app builder in "Program.cs" and contains an EF Core context instance.

The app nicely builds and runs. Swagger is correctly shown, routing ext/Extended as expected.
Still, when I try using PostMan to request to the WebApi the $select feature doesn't work at all. It won't give me any results but an infinite hanging on the request (despite debugging I can see the method is called and gives back the result). Interestingly, $top and $skip options are correctly working on the same route.

**UPDATE**

As requested, here's the implementation of the injected manager:

```
    public class MyTypeExtManager : IExtendedManager<MyType>
    {
       private readonly MyContext _context;

       public MyTypeExtManager(MyContext context)
       {
           _context = context;
       }

       public IQueryable<MyType> GetAll()
       {
          return _context.MyType; 
       }
    }
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: What is `_myTypeExtManager.GetAll()`? Show method body and signature.

Comment: Just updated the thread. @SvyatoslavDanyliv